# Symbol # in variable cannot be handled

Tags: debugging, abap

I got a CSV file from my front-end as a XString and after I convert it into String it looks as follows:

[image: debugger show variable]

In the next step I'm trying to perform `SPLIT lv_string AT '##' INTO TABLE itab` so I can get my data but it doesn't split anything, `itab` contains one line equal to `lv_string`.

If I try `REPLACE '#' IN lv_string WITH space`, `lv_string` doesn't change and `sy-subrc` is 4.

From my point of view I have this problem because the symbol `#` is used by SAP in this context as a symbol for [non-printable symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-printing_character_in_word_processors) (that result from the conversion byte->string).

My question is: how may I use SPLIT/REPLACE with `#` in this case?

I also thought that I can change the SAP code page when converting XString to String but I already use the SAP code page `4110` (utf-8) and don't know a better alternative...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you display a variable with the debugger, it displays the generic character `#` (U+0023) for all [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters) which are not assigned a glyph ("non-printable symbols" as you say).

If the variable corresponds to the contents of a text file, and `##` frequently occurs, there is a big chance that it's the combination of the control characters U+000D and U+000A which correspond to "[newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)" in Windows files.

In the backend debugger, you can check the hexadecimal values of those characters by clicking the button "Hexadezimal" (shown in your screenshot).

You may use the variable `CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>CR_LF` which contains those two control characters.

Comment: you are amazing! Thank you for your help and especially for the detailed explanation! I wish I could give you more points than I can!